# PXE boot from USB NIC

Tags: pxe-boot, usb-boot

Is there a USB solution to PXE boot? I want to use ghost or clonezilla or something to image a bunch of units that don't have on board ethernet, and no clear real way to add to it.

Answer (score 3):

Found this for you, haven't used it personally:

[Argon USB 10/100 with PXE](http://argontechnology.com/usb-fast-ethernet-with-pxe.html)